# Spring @schedule task does not return

Tags: java, spring, java-annotations

I have a Spring @scheduled task in my application that will start every 2 minutes. In some situation, the task never comes back so the task will not execute after this.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = ....)
private void task() {
}
```

Anyway to set a timeout for the scheduled task to force it end after a certain period of time?

Comment: I would recommend you to use fixedRate instead of fixedDelay

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to use fixed rate instead of fixed delay:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 1000)
private void task() {
}
```

The beginning of the task execution doesn’t wait for the completion of the previous execution when you use fixed rate. Also consider usage of `Future` in the internal of your business logic for preventing slow task to hang over long periods.